# NSNumberCurrencyFormatter negative format

Tags: objective-c, nsnumberformatter

I have a problem where if you change the currency on my app to something that differs from the locale, my app displays the negative value incorrectly e.g. App currency is set to £, locale is set to United States and my negative number is showing as ($278.00).  I would like it to display -£278.00.  I format the number using:

```
// Get the currency from the user settings/preferences
NSString *currency = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:CURRENCY_KEY];

// Set the format, currency and negative format so that we don't display the default (xx.xx)
NSNumberFormatter *numberCurrencyFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberCurrencyFormatter setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterCurrencyStyle];
[numberCurrencyFormatter setCurrencySymbol:currency];

[numberCurrencyFormatter setCurrencyDecimalSeparator:[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator]];

if ([[[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey:NSLocaleDecimalSeparator] isEqualToString:DECIMAL]) {
    [numberCurrencyFormatter setCurrencyGroupingSeparator:COMMA];
    [numberCurrencyFormatter setNegativeFormat:[currency stringByAppendingString:@"-#,##0.00"]];
} else {
    [numberCurrencyFormatter setCurrencyGroupingSeparator:DECIMAL];
    [numberCurrencyFormatter setNegativeFormat:[currency stringByAppendingString:@"-#.##0,00"]];
}

return [numberCurrencyFormatter stringFromNumber:number];
```

Comment: The currency format is based on the locale. Changing the formatter's currency symbol has no bearing on the locale. Someone in the USA always wants to see negative currency values as `(£278.00)` regardless of the currency. Same with the decimal separator and grouping character. These shouldn't change with the currency, only the locale. Why do you want to change the format just because the currency is pounds instead of dollars? What about when using the Euro? The Euro is used in many different locales with different formatting.

Comment: For example, i had my phone set to US locale but the currency on my app is set to £.  My positive values are showing as £x.00 whereas negative is showing the $.  I just want the currency symbol to be £ and not $?

Comment: You must be doing something else wrong. If all you do is create the number formatter, set the style to Currency, and set the currency symbol, it should just work. My own app does this. Get rid of all the extra code for setting the negative format and grouping separator.

Comment: Yes, it was the code setting the negative format and grouping separator, I guess I can just leave this up to the locale.  Thanks!